# Is it possible to do a Redshift Transaction with multiple files?

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to copy 5 files from S3 to 5 Redshift tables. I'd like to do an 'all or none' type of transaction where if one of the `COPY` commands fails, then nothing is copied over. So I've tried copying data in a `TRANSACTION`, but the transaction is still committing the `COPY` statements that completed before the errors were raised later in the script.

Is it possible to delay the full `COPY` commits until all of them are completed without errors?

Comment: Why? It is usually better to use Redshift as "append-only" as you can change history. You might consider using "version-id" and use it to get the latest version in your queries.

Comment: Are you running the query in some workbench?

Comment: @Guy I have no idea what you're talking about. And @viki888 the commands will be sent through a shell script, but Redshift executes the `COPY` commands itself. Does the workbench product make a difference?

Comment: The question is why do you need transactions. Historical records should not be modified, therefore, transactions are not critical usually in such use case. If you break a transaction to a set of discrete events, your life will be easier. If you want to COPY a batch of data that will be hidden from queries until all the data is ingested, using a version-id/date-stamp can help you, as your queries (with views?) will use the previous id/stamp until the next id/stamp becomes valid.

Answer (score 1):

"The COPY command is atomic and transactional." Read more on: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-multiple-files.html

I think if you really want to do it, you either can merge 5 files first then use a single copy, or code (use whatever script that can talk to Redshift through a driver) to simulate a transaction.

Comment: The only thing is that these files aren't going into the same table

Answer (score 0):

As @piggybox already mentioned, it is not possible directly. But you can use Python/ Java SDK to do the copy on individual tables and simulate a transaction.

If your tables are consumer facing and you do not want the data to be visible until all the tables are loaded, you can first load the data to staging tables and use a config table for the live status. Your Python/ Java script should keep polling this config table and as soon as the status is "ready/ good-to-go" for all the tables, you can do deep copy (insert as select) from the staging tables into the actual tables. These inserts will be DML so you can control them in a single transaction.